# Map from another JSON field by condition Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have json

```
{
  price: 0.0
  cost: 12.5
}
```

And model

```
public class Offer
{
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map data from JSON property "cost" when price = 0.0
But if price != 0.0, map from "price"

Comment: Do you only read the objects or do you also write the JSON later on? If you write, would it be important that `Price` would be 0.0 again, if it was unset when importing?

Comment: While you could shoehorn this into your deserialization logic if you really wanted to, it seems much more natural to deserialize both fields instead and put that logic in either property getters, or a new class that you (auto) map to. Deserialization should be "boring".

Comment: @Markus only read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a readonly property for this:

```
public class Offer
{
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cost")]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public decimal PriceOrCost  => Price == 0m ? Cost : Price;
}
```

Both properties are deserialized from JSON and you have an additional one that contains the condition. This property is marked with a `JsonIgnore` property in order not to write it to JSON when serializing.

Comment: I'd probably add a `[JsonIgnore]` to that property, to make it clear that it shouldn't be serialized when converting to JSON (which might happen for diagnostic purposes even if it's not used in production code). Also, it can be expression-bodied: `public decimal PriceOrCost => Price == 0m ? Cost : Price;`

Comment: Agreed. (to Zerlok)..  Don't mess with the deserialization logic.  Deserialization is/should-be dumb.  A read only "computed" property is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a json constructor

```
Offer price=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Offer>(json);

public class Offer
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Offer(decimal price, decimal cost)
    {
        Price = price == 0 ? cost : price;
    }
     public Offer() {}
}
```

you don't need to include all properties in the constructor, another properties can remain as it is.